# Is it possible to calculate a standard deviation from the gini coefficient and mean?

Tags: descriptive-statistics, gini

I am looking to create an analysis showing how many people in a given country have more than  than X dollars in income.
I know the average income, population count, and Gini Coefficient of income disparity.
Is it possible to back into X with those three data points?
Thank you so much in advance and apologies is this is a stupid question.
-Andrew

Comment: What do you mean "back into x"?